# devexpress gridcontrol refresh datasource

Tags: .net, devexpress, datasource, gridcontrol

with this code I populate a devexpress gridcontrol, everything is ok:

```
Private Sub tbccegek_SelectedPageChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraTab.TabPageChangedEventArgs) Handles tbccegek.SelectedPageChanged
    If tbccegek.SelectedTabPageIndex = 3 Then

        'gcCegek.DataSource = Nothing
        ConnectToDb(fbconn, "public")
        fbcommand.Connection = fbconn
        fbcommand.CommandText = "select cegazon, rovidnev, irsz||' '||varos||' '||utca||' '||hazszam as cim, adoszam, konyvpnem, osszktg_forg from cegek order by cegazon"
        fbadapter.SelectCommand = fbcommand

        fbadapter.Fill(fbdataset)
        fbdataset.Tables(0).TableName = "cegek"
        gcCegek.DataMember = "cegek"
        gcCegek.DataSource = fbdataset

        For i = 0 To fbdataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            If fbdataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5) = "1" Then
                fbdataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5) = "Összköltség"
            ElseIf fbdataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5) = "0" Then
                fbdataset.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(5) = "Forgalmi ktg."
            End If
        Next

        gcCegek.MainView.PopulateColumns()

        columnview = gcCegek.MainView
        columnview.Columns(0).Caption = "Cégazonosító"
        columnview.Columns(1).Caption = "Cégnév (rövid)"
        columnview.Columns(2).Caption = "Cím"
        columnview.Columns(3).Caption = "Adószám"
        columnview.Columns(4).Caption = "K.pnem"
        columnview.Columns(5).Caption = "Ktg.elsz"
        GridView1.BestFitColumns()

        fbconn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

But if I modify in the app a record, then save it via an update sql to the database and click again on the tab, on which the gridcontrol is, I see, that the value in the gridcontrol didn't change. But in the database, there is the modified value.

As you see, on the tabpage changing event I populate the grid from the very beginning, in my opinion there should be the modified value too.

Can you help me out?

Comment: How do you change the data and update the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to refetch data from the DB again to the DataSource to which the grid is connected to.  In this case, the grid will know that data was changed and refreshes its contents.

Also, I suggest that you set the breakpoint in the event handler you posted and make certain that the actual modified data is fetched from the DB.

Also, it is more correct to use the following code:

```
if not e.Page Is Nothing andalso e.Page.SelectedTabPageIndex = 3 Then
...
```

Comment: I set fbdataset = New DataSet befor all the code and now it works correctly.